# ClassNotFoundException while executing mvn javadoc:javadoc

Tags: java, maven

My build works fine except when doing a release (or more precisely mvn javadoc:javadoc).
I get the ClassNotFoundException below. Any hints as to how to provide the class would be deeply appreciated

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequest
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:386)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.buildJavadocOptions(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:5843)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.executeReport(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:1857)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.JavadocReport.generate(JavadocReport.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.JavadocReport.execute(JavadocReport.java:315)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: I've gotten this to work with maven-javadoc-plugin 2.9; However 2.9.1 fails with the above error.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem of maven transitive dependencies conflict. Some dependencies are transitively depend on two different version of httpclient, try to exclude one with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that the OP was running on `Maven 2.x`. So, the solution would be to use `Maven 3.x` if they want to work with recent versions of `maven-javadoc-plugin` (apparently `2.9+`). After all the `Maven 2` has reached its [EOL](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html), so there's no reason to continue to using it.

A combination of changes like the `maven-javadoc-plugin` upgrade to use a newer version of `HttpClient` and `Maven` moving from `Plexus` to `Guice` as `IoC` container may have caused this.

Here are a few ticket links that could help:

- [Required class missing: org/apache/http/HttpRequest](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAVADOC-375)
- [[Patch]
  Port maven-javadoc-plugin from httpclient 3 to httpclient 4](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAVADOC-363)
- [Move
  from Plexus to Guice as IoC container](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4749)